# @PathVariable with slashes in middle of RequestMapping URL

Tags: spring-boot, request-mapping, path-variables

I have a Spring controller mapping like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/{pathVar1}/receipt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String generateReceipt(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String pathVar1) {
....
}
```

In this case what if the pathVar1 has slash('/'). 
Example request:

> 'api/CODE/1/receipt'

pathVar1 is supplied with

> 'CODE/1'

.

Comment: so what do you want pathVar1  to be actually?

Comment: Want it to accept the value having slash.
if I send this:
'api/CODE/1/receipt' API is not recognized because it was expecting 'api/CODE/receipt' two slashes only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not the cleanest solution, but it seems to be working:

Replace `@PathVariable` in API path with `**` to accept anything between "api/" and "/receipt", and then extract the needed part of path.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "api/**/receipt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String generateReceipt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    String bestMatchPattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    String apiPath = new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(bestMatchPattern, path);
    String neededPathVariableValue = apiPath.substring(0, apiPath.length() - "/receipt".length());

    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, I am checking this out. Let me know if there is any other alternative for this.